# Writing a SmsReceiver that doesn't let other applications to receive sms

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an app with a SmsReceiver. I want this class to receive message texts that contains a special word, like "SPY", and don't let other recievers, receive such messages. how can I do it?

 here is the **receiver class**

```
package com.newidea.repairmycontacts;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;


public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final static String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private final String TAG = "SmsReceiver";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //onReceiveWithPrivilege(context, intent, false);
    if(!intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED))
        return;
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(bundle==null)
        return;
    Object[] pdus=(Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    String Body="";
    for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++)
        Body += SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]).getMessageBody().toString()+"\n";
    String Address=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]).getOriginatingAddress();

    Toast.makeText(context, "Message from "+Address+" : "+Body, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.newidea.repairmycontacts"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.newidea.repairmycontacts.SMSList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're writing some sort of malware...

Comment: nop :) it's an App like "Private Space" that seperates some contacts & SMSs from android system and save them somewhere else. this way, user can hide some relationships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set a priority on your intent-filter tag for .SmsReceiver like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Be aware that this will work with stock messaging app, but some other sms apps use other priorities and may get on top of yours...

After if you want to prevent other apps from receiving the broadcast, you can use:

```
BroadcastReceiver.abortBroadcast()
```

Keep in mind that this is fragile specially with other sms apps.